# How many ways to use Amazon Web Services for basic authentication / profile functionalities in iOS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, ios13, swift5, aws-amplify

I want to use AWS services into my app for authentication and basic functionalities which include : Login, Register, Forgot Password, Change Password, Delete account, etc.

I have searched a lot and found that there are many ways :

- By using Amplify Framework
- AWS Mobile client
- By Amazon Cognito
- By Identity Provider

Actually, I am little confused, what is the difference between all these ? Which one is the best way to implement ? And while go for documentation, there are so many official documentation about it on google. Which can be consider ?

- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift
- https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSMobileClient/index.html
- https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSCognito/index.html
- https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSAuthCore/index.html
- https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSCognitoAuth/index.html

What are all these use for ? Can anyone differentiate ?

Answer (score 1):

these are all abstractions on top of the lower level generated Cognito Client designed to make it easier on the developer to call Cognito API's. The lowest level ones are AWSCognito, AWSAuthCore, and AWSCognitoAuth. The AWSMobileClient is a higher level abstraction built on top of all of these to make it easier to hit the Cognito API's in a way most developers can understand (Cognito can be fairly complex) and is the one the Mobile SDK teams here at AWS recommend using. Amplify will have an Auth category which will be an even higher level abstraction and will also be generic to any auth provider when it is done but right now it's still in progress( you can track PR's for the Auth category [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/pull/400) and [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/pull/405)) thus Amplify is depending on the AWSMobileClient for auth at the moment.